# Describe a product line with Schema.org

Tags: product, schema.org

We create a website for a bikeshop. In the first step we will just show the product line like mountainbike, BMX, racer or children bike.
We want to describe the product line with a headline, text and a picture.

Is it possible to describe a product line with Schema.org?
I just found a Schema.org type for a product.

Comment: Do you mean categories, i.e., a link "BMX" that leads to a list of all BMX products?

Comment: it doesnt link to products. it just describes which type of products are availible in the local store.

Comment: Yes, I would start with http://schema.org/Product. You can find a Microdata example at the bottom.